# Regular expression for address

Tags: asp.net

I want to write a regular expression for a postal address i.e.

> 20 rose Street or 130 Qeens road

I have tried `[0-9]{1,2,3,4}[A-Za-z]` but its not working

any suggestions

Comment: We can't really see a pattern from one isolated example. You need to provide more examples and explain what you want to get out of the input as well. Please also explain what you mean by "its not working", as this is a poor description of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, this should work:

`[0-9]{1,} [a-zA-Z]{1,}( [a-zA-Z]{1,}){1,}`

Also if you want to allow apartment numbers on the end you could tack this on

`([0-9]{1,} [a-zA-Z]{1,}( [a-zA-Z]{1,}){1,})( [0-9]{1,})?`

Answer (score -1):

If is for MySQL try this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Ex. All email @gmail.com and @yahoo.com

SELECT * FROM customer where email REGEXP  'gmail.com|yahoo.com' group by email;